# How to add onClick event in Link

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink

I have below `Link` code in ReactJs for which trying to add `onClick` event which is not getting fired.

Functional stateless Component

```
export default function ResultChip({chipName, downloadTestResults}) {

return (
<Card className={classes.card}>
  <CardContent>   
    {
     chipName == "Download results" &&
     <Typography style ={{marginTop: 15, fontWeight: 3}}>
     <Link style={{ fontWeight: 2, color: '#087063', letterSpacing: '0.28' }} onClick={downloadTestResults}> {botTestAPIResult.uploadedFilename} </Link>
     </Typography>
    }
  </CardContent>
</Card>
);
}
```

and here is my ContainerComponent

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ResultChip extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state= {
    }  
    this.downloadTestResults = this.downloadTestResults.bind(this);   
 }

 downloadTestResults = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Perform some action here    
 }

  render() {   
    return (
        <div>
        </div>
    )
   }
   }
```

Why my click event is not getting fired? Is some connectivity missing between component and Container? What's wrong?

Comment: What is `Link` in your component. Where are you import `Link`

Comment: @jdn Link is Materila UI component `import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';`

Comment: How you call `ResultChip` in `ContainerComponent` ?

Comment: @jdn I haven't done, very new to ReactJs, so trying to learn.Could you please point me where and how to call? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You export `ResultChip` like this:

```
export default function ResultChip({chipName, downloadTestResults}) {

return (
   <Card className={classes.card}>
      <CardContent>   
      {
        chipName == "Download results" &&
        <Typography style ={{marginTop: 15, fontWeight: 3}}>
        <Link onClick={downloadTestResults}> {botTestAPIResult.uploadedFilename}</Link>
        </Typography>
      }
      </CardContent>
   </Card>
);
}
```

Call `ResultChip` in your `ContainerComponent`:

```
import ResultChip from '...';

downloadTestResults = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Perform some action here    
}
render() {
   return (
      <div>
         <ResultChip 
           downloadTestResults={this.downloadTestResults} 
           chipName={...}
         />
      </div>
   )
}
```

Comment: Tried to implement the code shared but sorry to inform that its still not working. Click event not firing up

Comment: Check my codesandbox for example: https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-mountain-cbgh6